# Can I get messagebox's icon="warning" noise on a custom Tkinter Toplevel() window?

Tags: python, tkinter, warnings, messagebox

I like the warning noise that messagebox provides out of the box (no pun intended), as in the GUI below.

```
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showinfo("my title", "my message", icon="warning", parent=None)
```

However, I need more customization than messagebox offers, so I've created my own window. Is there a way to include the same warning noise with a Toplevel() window?

I'm using Python3 and Tkinter 8.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would need to manually sound it

```
import Tkinter 
Tkinter.Tk().bell()
```

or maybe you can just do `SomeWindow.bell()` (to be honest im not overly familiar with tkinter)

Comment: For Tkinter 8.5, your 2nd suggestion, as in something like `myWindow.bell()`, worked nicely. Thank you!